# what is the difference between extends Recyclerview.Adapter vs RecyclerView.Adapter<SubclassRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have been reading online about RecyclerView in Android. As a beginner, I have seen some online tutorials extend `RecyclerView.Adapter<Subclass_RecyclerviewAdapter.ViewHolder>` and some `RecylerView.Adapter` only. Actually, what is the difference between them? which is better?

Answer (score 1):

If I do this:

```
class SimpleAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter() { ... }
```

then Android Studio says "One type argument expected for class `Adapther<VH: RecyclerView.ViewHolder!>`". In the source for the `RecyclerView`, you can see:

```
public class RecyclerView extends ViewGroup implements ScrollingView,
        NestedScrollingChild2, NestedScrollingChild3 {

    ...

    public abstract static class Adapter<VH extends ViewHolder> { ... }

    ... 

}
```

That means you have to supply a *type* to the `Adapter` constructor (similar to how you don't define a `List`, but a `List<String>` for example).

There is a thing to note here, though. You can put `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` as the type, or you can extend this class and use your custom `ViewHolder`. This allows you to define custom methods on the `ViewHolder`, for example:

```
inner class SimpleViewHolder(private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind(text: String) {
        // Bind to the view
    }
}
```

EDIT: Important thing is, you receive the type you use in the constructor in the adapter methods, for example: `override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SimpleViewHolder, position: Int) { ... }`, where you can then use your methods from the custom view holder.

And, you will have to have a custom VH, as the RecyclerView.ViewHolder is *abstract*.